# The machine is (worked-made ) by wind power?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

I am not sure  but i think that correct is to say that the machine is worked by wind power, what is your opinion ?

Comment: The machine runs on wind power.

Comment: Are you expecting the hyphenated word "worked-made" to say that the machine is made to work by the power of the wind?

Answer (score 1):

It would be shorter to say "The machine is wind powered" (or "wind-powered") or "The machine is powered by wind".

If you like 'work', then it could be said "The machine works by wind power". Also "The machine works using wind power" and "The machine works by using wind power" are all ok.

A slightly longer version: I can imagine some people saying "The machine is made to work by wind power" - which seems to put emphasis on "made" rather than the machine itself, so it implies something about the design process perhaps.

Your option of "The machine is worked by wind power" would be confusing because "work" is most commonly an intransitive verb, which means it doesn't take a preposition after it (i.e. to be worked "by"), except in cases where work is being done on the object of the sentence, in this case usually by people or animals, or I guess robots too. E.g. "They worked the clay into bricks" can be written in a passive voice "The clay was worked into bricks", or including the workers at the end also works, e.g. "The clay was worked into bricks by the people". However that structure doesn't work in this case, since there is no subject 'working' anything, only an object that works (the machine).

Hope that helps.